# elm: copy text to clipboard

Tags: clipboard, elm, clipboard.js

Is there a way to copy a text from a div to clipboard when user clicks a button in elm 0.18?

I have looked at [Clipboard.elm](https://github.com/jdudek/elm-clipboard) but I cannot make it compile and work in elm 0.18. So is there an official working way to do this in elm 0.18?

Comment: There a very few libraries that wrap js because they can't be published. So you will probably want to use a port. In this case that would be quite straight forward as you only need one way (to js) communication and that's the easier bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the target browser supports it, then you
can do it via ports, for example:

elm:

```elm
type Msg = Copy

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case Debug.log "msg" msg of
    Copy -> (model, copy ())

port copy : () -> Cmd msg

-- VIEW
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ Html.input [ id "copy" ] []
    , Html.button [ onClick Copy ] [ text "copy" ]
    ]
```

javascript:

```js
const app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();
app.ports.copy.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('copy');
  document.querySelector('#copy').select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work in Firefox 41+ which is strict about the context in which you can execute the copy command. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility for (a little) more info. Someone with a better understanding of the Elm runtime can probably explain why the callback isn't invoked in the event cycle...

Answer (score 1):

As of Elm 0.19 a [custom web component](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/custom_elements.html) might be a good way to do this. I've had success with [this one](https://github.com/github/clipboard-copy-element).